# Return Object by value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, pass-by-reference, creation

I know that Objects in Javascript are passed by reference, but is there any way to return object as values.

When multiple calls to decodePermissions(), they always share same object. So my question is, It is there any way to create object for each call?

```
function decodePermissions(table, group) {
    return {
            add: canPerformAction(table, group, ACTION.ADD),
            edit: canPerformAction(table, group, ACTION.EDIT),
            delete: canPerformAction(table, group, ACTION.DELETE)
        }
}
```

Comment: Your `return` statement should create an object each time, so no sharing here. What is the actual problem?

Comment: why not just passing the object shared to the function and return it inside the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that everytime the function decodePermissions(table, group).add(table, group, ACTION.ADD); is called, you want to create a fresh new object.

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I have attached a rudimentary example on the jsbin link below

https://jsbin.com/jofikudite/edit?html,js,console,output

Each time objCreator.createNewObject(param) is called, it creates a fresh new object that is not in any way linked to other objects created via this function.

Comment: My pleasure. Glad that helped :).

Answer (score 0):

No, You can deep copy the object and return that new object

```
function returnObj( obj )
{
  return JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( obj ) );
}
```

Comment: It's not deepcopy its just changing object to JSON then changing it back to Object you just lose here reference to object in memory ;)

Comment: I didint downvote u ... and ye it is :) Probably someone downvote you cuz you didi answer question that is x*N answers on stack i didint for sure downvote u;p\

Comment: @Alex sorry, I didn't mean to shout like this, but have been seeing this kind of policing since yesterday now and lost my cool. Still would like to understand how it didn't answer the question